# How to convert multiple Geospatial PDFs to map tiles

Tags: convert, merge, geospatial-pdf, xyz-tiles

What is the best way to convert Geo-referenced PDF files (like the Canadian BC http://pub.data.gov.bc.ca/datasets/177864/pdf/ or USGS maps) to a collection of tiled XYZ web maps.

I would like to retain as much detail from the PDF's as possible (ie: sharp lines at say map tile zoom of 18) so an ultimate solution would convert directly from the geospatial PDFs to tiles, however I assume this cant be done due to map stitching steps?

I wish to do this with open-source software where possible (I already have gdal installed).

Please also include recommended map formats for any intermediary steps required.